# Consumable Items Wasted

Tags: shadowrun-returns

When a run is completed, are the unused consumable items I equipped to a hired runner returned to me or gone forever?

On one run it appeared as if the runner had the unused items in her inventory at the start of the next run, other times this didn't happen. Could it have been coincidence that the items at the next run were the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All consumable items you gave a hired runner is gone.  It won't be back even if you rehire them for the next run.  Each runner has a default set of items they will always have, so if you use it up they'll have those items again (or upgrades of them in certain cases) for the next run.

Comment: Is this true for Dragonfall, as well? What about the recurring, non-hired characters (the ones in your safehouse)?

Comment: @walrushelmet i'm not sure since I didn't really use consummables on my squad in dragonfall

Comment: What about the ones the squad comes with? Do those come back after the mission is over?

Comment: Just checked; used Glory's medkits, she had all of them back on the next run.

Answer (score 2):

In Dragonfall, NPC runners have a predefined inventory that regenerates after each run. If you use the items they bring, they'll replace them post run. From my experience, this is at no cost to you.

I tested this by using all of Glory's medkits on a run. On the next, she had them back again.